# This row already belongs to this table while binding the SpAudit Entries

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, ssom, spaudit, spauditeventtype

Can any one help me in knowing what's wrong in my code
Because I want all the columns from Audit entries should get create in my Data Row dynamically

```
using (SPSite mysiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = mysiteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPAuditQuery query = new SPAuditQuery(mysiteCollection);
                query.SetRangeStart(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
                query.SetRangeEnd(DateTime.Now);
                SPAuditEntryCollection auditCol = mysiteCollection.Audit.GetEntries(query);

              DataTable dtAudit = new DataTable();
         dtAudit.Columns.Add("NewColumn", typeof(System.String));

         foreach (SPAuditEntry entry in auditCol)
         {
              if (entry.Event == SPAuditEventType.Update)
              {
                  DataRow dRow = dtAudit.Rows.Add();
                  dRow["NewColumn"] = entry.MachineName;
                  dtAudit.Rows.Add(dRow);
              }
          }

                GridView1.DataSource = dtAudit;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to this line `dRow["NewColumn"] = entry.MachineName;` where the `entry.MachineName` returns as **NULL**. (Debugged on my side)

> Unfortunately, By **Design** the returned values of the `MachineName`
>   and `MachineIP` are always **NULL** for **Privacy concerns**.

**Besides** the above issue, There is a bit syntax issue related to this line

`DataRow dRow = dtAudit.Rows.Add();` it should be `dtAudit.NewRow();`

---

So in your code, you should exclude both `MachineIP` and `MachineName` columns when you tried to show the `SPAuditEntryCollection` data.

Also, Make sure that the value of retrieved column is not **NULL** before adding a new row in `dtAudit` datatable to avoid the null value exception and fix `dtAudit.Rows.Add();` to be `dtAudit.NewRow();` as the following:

```
if (entry.MachineName != null)
 {
   DataRow dRow = dtAudit.NewRow();       
   dRow["NewColumn"] = entry.MachineName;
   dtAudit.Rows.Add(dRow);
 }
```

**Output**

Empty value for `MachineName`

[image]

Comment: Can you please help me in knowing the alternative way to get all columns and values of audit

Comment: Sure, from entry object you can find all columns, so sjut type entry then do and you will get the columns name that is Site Id,Item Id,Item Type User Id,Machine Name,Machine IP,Document Location,Location Type ,Event ... etc

Comment: Please don't hesitate to ask in case, you need additional clarification, by the way, don't forget to **Mark**  and **Upvote** the correct answer!